# How long does an angular promise live?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to understand the life cycle of angular services and components.

Say I have a controller that uses an http service:

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/service').success(function(data) {
    // handle the response
  });
}
```

The thing is that this controller may be attached to a view. And I want to make sure that the response is discarded if the view has been removed, this is to prevent conflicts with other requests thay may be triggered in other parts of the application. Will the instance of the controller be destroyed and with it, pending calls from the `$http` service be canceled if the view is removed? For example, when the user navigates away (without reloading) from the page causing a Javascript render of a new section?

[**Edit**] I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4839/) that shows that, at least for the $timeout service, the pending operations are still running after the `$scope` is destroyed by navigating away. Is there a simple way to attach async operations to the scope so that they will be destroyed automatically?

Comment: Why don't you test it? As it is you'd need to provide more information  about your app to get a conclusive answer.

Comment: Done: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4839/. I edited the question to include what I tried.

Comment: You haven't really explained the lifecycle of your Controller. Your Scope will live as long as your controller lives. Your controller will live as long as it's in the DOM and registered in Angular (`ng-if` and `ng-view` with routing will destroy DOM and rebuild new instances of it, `ng-show` will not). AJAX services are AJAX services: the call is going to live inside of the browser's memory, safe from garbage-collection, in a closure, until there are no more references to it. ie: $scope can't be GCd until the call's done, the call can't be GCd until the controller is gone...

Comment: There's nothing particularly Angular-specific in the question: the promise is going to live as long as something has reference to it.  Where angular comes in is whether you have Angular directives which add/remove DOM (`ng-if`, `ng-repeat`, `ng-view`), or you have Angular directives which are just showing/hiding the DOM, and thus not destroying/reinstantiating controllers, because a promise will live for an indeterminate amount of time.  It's just JS in a closure.

Comment: Well, when I said 'when the view is destroyed', and 'For example, navigating away from the page', I was trying to explicitly say that the DOM would be modified, destroying the current instance of the controller. I never said anything about 'hiding'.

Comment: When you navigate away, the promise is living on in the `$templateCache`. If you don't reference the explicit rejection of the promise when the `$scope` is destroyed, you'll leave it out there like you are experiencing.

Comment: @norguard I wouldn't go so far as to say there's nothing angular specific about the question. Without some real insight and expert to ninja level angular experience, you might be expected to believe things like this are automatically destroyed within `$scope` lifecycle

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch but a decent JS guy could tell you that if the AJAX call and the promise's callback subscriptions touched absolutely nothing outside of the Controller's closure, and you know that your DOM is being destroyed, and that the only thing the Controller governs is its view and the view of its children, then unless the call isn't idempotent, it's not going to matter whether the call succeeds, fails, aborts, is aborted, et cetera, to anyone but a person who is sitting with their console open (would see it anyway), assuming that DOM (and angular scopes/bindings) are being destroyed.

Comment: duh. but well... wasn't the question. :).  I've learned not to go down the "you shouldn't care about that" road on StackOverflow, unless that's what the asker is soliciting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, attach a reference to your promise, then pass that reference to the `cancel` function.  This resolves the promise with a rejections.  So you could also just use `promise.reject()` in place of `cancel(promise)`

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
  var promise =  $http.get('/service');

  promise.success(function(data){

  });

   $scope.$on(
         "$destroy",
         function() {
            promise.reject("scope destroyed, promise no longer available");
         }
   );
}
```

Comment: This is not working in my angular app. There is an JavaScript Error saying function is not available. So where does cancel come from??? Do you mean $timeout.cancel()?

Comment: It's been a while, so not entirely sure, but that would be my guess.  I use `reject()` on promise objects these days as it conforms to the Promise/A+ standard.  I'll edit my answer.